# Is ConditionalAttribute supposed to strip out entire lines, or just method calls?

Tags: .net, debugging, conditional-statements, release

According to the documentation on the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) class:

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a
>   method indicates to compilers that a
>   call to the method should not be
>   compiled into Microsoft intermediate
>   language (MSIL) unless the conditional
>   compilation symbol that is associated
>   with ConditionalAttribute is defined.

To me this is saying that the `Conditional` attribute only alters behavior at the individual method call level. But consider the following code snippet:

```
class InstanceType
{
    public InstanceType DoSideEffects()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Side effects!");
        return this;
    }

    public InstanceType DoMoreSideEffects()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("More side effects!");
        return this;
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public void ConditionalMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Conditional method run.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new InstanceType();

        // The compiler appears to strip out this entire line
        // in a Release build.
        x.DoSideEffects().DoMoreSideEffects().ConditionalMethod();

        var y = new InstanceType();

        // When each method call appears on its own line,
        // the first two methods are included as expected.
        y.DoSideEffects();
        y.DoMoreSideEffects();
        y.ConditionalMethod();
    }
}
```

Compare the outputs of Debug and Release builds:

```
DEBUG                    RELEASE
Side effects!            Side effects!
More side effects!       More side effects!
Conditional method run.
Side effects!
More side effects!
Conditional method run.
```

**Is this behavior specified somewhere?** I had thought that both builds were supposed to have the same output except for the lines reading "Conditional method run."

Comment: My understanding of `[Conditional]` is the same as yours, and I think you are seeing the effect of an optimization take place here.  What does the IL look like in release mode?

Comment: Interestingly enough, even Visual Studio (or is it ReSharper?) colors the whole line gray/unused in the first case, if you do not define DEBUG. Whereas in the second, it only colors the call to ConditionalMethod() gray/unused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does .NET's Conditional Attribute Cause Side-Effects to be Removed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410865/why-does-nets-conditional-attribute-cause-side-effects-to-be-removed)

Comment: @Adam: Admittedly the two questions are similar... however, the other question asks about side-effects occurring as a result of evaluating the argument passed *to* a method marked with the `Conditional` attribute. This one is about the sequence of method calls providing the instance on which said method is called. So I feel that the two are sufficiently distinct. If others disagree and vote to close, I guess that's fine too.

Comment: True, though the answers on that question answer your question (specifically the points about `#if`/`#endif` as what ConditionalAttribute is replacing).

Answer (score 3):

Interessting feature :-) I've never noticed that.

I've taken a look at the IL. This doesn't explain the behaviour (the compilation process), but it documents the result anyway, I believe.

The whole C# code line is clearly left out in the IL:

- In the DEBUG compilation a new object
  is created (the x variable), stored
  at location 0 and loaded. Afterwards
  the three methods are applied
  successively: DoSideEffects(),
  DeMoreSideEffects(), and
  ConditionalMethod()
- In the RELEASE compilation the variable still gets created, but since it is not needed, it is immediately pop'ed. Instead the y variable is stored at location 0 and loaded.

To me, this looks like a bug, really. It seems that it would have been possible to just exclude the ConditionalMethod() call in the IL. But it seems that you are right, that the whole line is left out.

```
// DEBUG compilation
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       58 (0x3a)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType V_0,
           class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoSideEffects()
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoMoreSideEffects()
  IL_0012:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::ConditionalMethod()
  IL_0017:  nop
  IL_0018:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::.ctor()
  IL_001d:  stloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.1
  IL_001f:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoSideEffects()
  IL_0024:  pop
  IL_0025:  ldloc.1
  IL_0026:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoMoreSideEffects()
  IL_002b:  pop
  IL_002c:  ldloc.1
  IL_002d:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::ConditionalMethod()
  IL_0032:  nop
  IL_0033:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
  IL_0038:  pop
  IL_0039:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main

// RELEASE compilation
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       33 (0x21)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType y)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  pop
  IL_0006:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::.ctor()
  IL_000b:  stloc.0
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoSideEffects()
  IL_0012:  pop
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  callvirt   instance class ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType ConsoleApplication3.InstanceType::DoMoreSideEffects()
  IL_0019:  pop
  IL_001a:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
  IL_001f:  pop
  IL_0020:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: I think this is a feature. I am using this feature to ensure that an expression with side-effects is only evaluated in debug mode and not production.

Comment: Oh, I was confused and read too quickly. I definitely agree that this is not what I expect when using extension method syntax. Very surprising behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry drag up such an old post, but I just encountered the same thing and this was the only discussion of this issue that I could find.

I have a hunch as to what is going on.  The `[Conditional]` is stripping the call to `ConditionalMethod()` *as well as* any expressions that act as parameters passed to it (as per the documentation, and the other thread linked above).

My guess is that the implicit `this` parameter is being treated exactly the same way.  In the line `x.DoSideEffects().DoMoreSideEffects().ConditionalMethod();` the expression that is passed as `this` is `x.DoSideEffects().DoMoreSideEffects()` which is dutifully stripped, eliminating the side effects.

If we rewrite into pseudo code where we explicitly pass `this` as the first parameter to each method it becomes much clearer:

`ConditionalMethod( DoMoreSideEffects( DoSideEffects( x )));`